# Limiting solr (not java) to use a certain amount of memory

Tags: solr

I know I can pass parameters to java to limit the amount of memory used, but that doesn't change the application behavior. (assuming I will get an out of memory exception or similar)

I would like to limit the amount of memory that solr uses. I am assuming it is as simple as setting a single configuration option, but googling so far has been fruitless.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Edit: I just want to note that I understand there will be a tradeoff between memory usage and execution speed. In this case, I am willing to sacrifice speed to reduce memory footprint. I also understand that it is possible that solr does not support the option of tuning this tradeoff.

Answer (score 1):

Solr's memory limit is the JVM's heap memory limit.  There's no separate configuration.

The notes [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPerformanceFactors#RAM_Usage_Considerations) indicate that Solr's memory usage will indeed eclipse the JVM's limit on occasion, but that it will attempt to "make it right" by freeing heap space when an `OutOfMemoryError` is fired.

Answer (score 1):

This page has a ton of useful information on how to reduce/optimize Solr's memory consumption.

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPerformanceFactors

But I will point out one major thing from this document:

> The number of indexed fields greatly increases the following:
>
> - **Memory usage during indexing**
> - Segment merge time
> - Optimization times
> - Index size

Double-check to ensure you aren't indexing fields you will never search on in your schema.xml file.

Also, in that document, take a look at "Factors Affecting Memory Usage" at the bottom of the page.

Hope this helps,

-C